# Indicator for accuracy of prediction during run time (without ground truth)

Tags: regression, time-series, accuracy

I am solving a supervised learning problem. The nature of the problem involves time series and a single target variable. After training I implemented the model. Now I like to give an indicator of the accuracy of the predictions. Of course the error cannot be calculated since during the the run time the ground truth is not available. 
Is it possible to provide an indicator of accuracy (ideally an estimate of variance of error) without having the ground truth? For example training another model?